# Why Does Select Top X Kill Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the T-SQL Query below (generated by linq-to-sql, so it looks a bit weird.)  When I *remove* the top 10, it runs in under 1 second.  When I leave the top 10 in, it takes 68 seconds.

Without the top 10, the total number of rows is only 19.

Why does the top 10 destroy performance so much in this situation?

```
SELECT TOP (10) [t3].[value] AS [StartDate], [t3].[AH_TimeStamp4] AS [EndDate], [t3].[value2] AS [RunTime], [t3].[AH_Idnr] AS [RunNumber], [t3].[AH_Status] AS [StatusCode], [t3].[STATUS_DESC] AS [StatusDesc], [t3].[STATUS_TYPE] AS [StatusType]
FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE([t1].[AH_TimeStamp2],[t1].[AH_TimeStamp1]) AS [value], [t1].[AH_TimeStamp4], CONVERT(BigInt,(((CONVERT(BigInt,DATEDIFF(DAY, [t1].[AH_TimeStamp1], [t1].[AH_TimeStamp4]))) * 86400000) + DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, [t1].[AH_TimeStamp1], [t1].[AH_TimeStamp4]), [t1].[AH_TimeStamp1]), [t1].[AH_TimeStamp4])) * 10000) AS [value2], [t1].[AH_Idnr], [t1].[AH_Status], [t2].[STATUS_DESC], [t2].[STATUS_TYPE], [t0].[OH_Name]
    FROM [dbo].[OH] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AH] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[OH_Idnr]) = [t1].[AH_OH_Idnr]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CHK_JOB_STATUS_CODE] AS [t2] ON [t1].[AH_Status] = ([t2].[STATUS_CODE])
    ) AS [t3]
WHERE [t3].[OH_Name] = @p0
ORDER BY [t3].[AH_Idnr] DESC
```

Edit ->  as requested, here's the linq-generated query without the Take(10)

```
SELECT [t3].[value] AS [StartDate], [t3].[AH_TimeStamp4] AS [EndDate], [t3].[value2] AS [RunTime], [t3].[AH_Idnr] AS [RunNumber], [t3].[AH_Status] AS [StatusCode], [t3].[STATUS_DESC] AS [StatusDesc], [t3].[STATUS_TYPE] AS [StatusType]
FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE([t1].[AH_TimeStamp2],[t1].[AH_TimeStamp1]) AS [value], [t1].[AH_TimeStamp4], CONVERT(BigInt,(((CONVERT(BigInt,DATEDIFF(DAY, [t1].[AH_TimeStamp1], [t1].[AH_TimeStamp4]))) * 86400000) + DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, [t1].[AH_TimeStamp1], [t1].[AH_TimeStamp4]), [t1].[AH_TimeStamp1]), [t1].[AH_TimeStamp4])) * 10000) AS [value2], [t1].[AH_Idnr], [t1].[AH_Status], [t2].[STATUS_DESC], [t2].[STATUS_TYPE], [t0].[OH_Name]
    FROM [dbo].[OH] AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AH] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[OH_Idnr]) = [t1].[AH_OH_Idnr]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CHK_JOB_STATUS_CODE] AS [t2] ON [t1].[AH_Status] = ([t2].[STATUS_CODE])
    ) AS [t3]
WHERE [t3].[OH_Name] = @p0
ORDER BY [t3].[AH_Idnr] DESC
```

Edit 2 -> here's the LINQ Query - nothing special, just 3 joins

```
List<UC4Status> statusList = uc4DB.OHs.Where(o => o.OH_Name == jobName).Join(uc4DB.AHs, oh => oh.OH_Idnr, ah => ah.AH_OH_Idnr, (oh, ah) => ah)
                        .Join(uc4DB.CHK_JOB_STATUS_CODEs, ah => ah.AH_Status, job => job.STATUS_CODE, (a, s) =>
                            new UC4Status
                            {
                                StartDate = a.AH_TimeStamp2 ?? a.AH_TimeStamp1,
                                EndDate = a.AH_TimeStamp4,
                                RunTime = a.AH_TimeStamp4 - a.AH_TimeStamp1,
                                StatusType = s.STATUS_TYPE,
                                StatusDesc = s.STATUS_DESC,
                                StatusCode = a.AH_Status,
                                RunNumber = a.AH_Idnr
                            }).OrderByDescending(r => r.RunNumber).Take(maxResults).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you post the generated query without the .Take(10) on the linq to sql curious if anything else about the query changes (it shouldn't but you never know)

Comment: Also, taking the query generated in both cases, can you post the execution plan? If you have SQL Management Studio installed, you can get it by pressing Control-L with the query highlighted.

Comment: Oh also could you post the linq statement that generates this sql?  We might get farther by trying to optimize from the linq statement side.

Comment: I can't get the execution plan - apparently I don't have sufficient permissions on the database to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More important than the number of rows returned are the number of rows in each table joined.  Without access to the query plan it is hard to say what the issue is.  But, the issue could likely be due to outdated or missing column statistics combined with a lack of good indexes causing the query optimizer make a very bad decision when `top` is used.  For example, if the optimizer incorrectly makes the assumption that the `top` statement will only operate on a small number of rows in each joined table, it could select to use inner loop joins with table scans on each joined table -- which could be a horribly slow operation on a large number of records (but can work very efficiently when working with only few records).  In the case without `top`, the optimizer could correctly assume that it will have to scan a large volume of records in the joined tables and use an approach that better suits such an operation, such as a hash match join from a table scan.

You can try updating statistics and adding other indexes to see if that helps.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  One of my tables has millions of rows, but I had thought anything in the SELECT was done after everything in the FROM, but I guess this is an example of the optimizer going against this simplified conceptual model for performance

Comment: Even though it is placed in the "select" clause, "top" is more closely related to the "where" clause, since it acts as a criterion for continuing to return records.  And since it is effectively part of the "where" clause in that sense, the optimizer can attempt to pick a more efficient approach, accordingly, cutting down resource consumption dramatically in many cases, such as by bypassing temp db or by narrowing down a base table to just a few records and then operating only on those when joining with other tables.  ...In a nutshell, that is.

Answer (score 0):

What's the number of rows without the top 10? Are there any indexes implemented?
I would guess it's due to the subquery joins of t0, t1, and t2...
Can you try something like,

```
select top 10 * from (
  select t3.value....
  from ( 
    select coalesce... )
  where ... order by ... 
)
```

Comment: Total rows returned by this query (without the take) is like 19.  I would think SQL Server would care.